# Is there a sample MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to learn SQL by creating and running queries. However, it does not seem like a great idea to build some bogus data, so, does anyone know a free sample database to download?

Comment: a google search might have yielded easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see theses links

- [MySQL Documentation: Other MySQL Documentation - Example Databases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html)
- [MySQL Sample Database](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx)
- [any sample MySQL databases I can download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609/any-sample-mysql-databases-i-can-download)

Answer (score 5):

Someone ported AdventureWorks to MySQL: http://sourceforge.net/projects/awmysql/files/

Answer (score 2):

There are four different ones to download [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html), under "Example Databases".

Answer (score 1):

[Here it is :)](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx)

The interesting part is that you can learn from the very site and use that sample database while learning.

Answer (score 0):

I started learning MySql by downloading the employee DB from the mysql website(link provided in above answers). You can view the structure of the db, install and can perform all the PL/SQL operations on it. I have not tried the adventureworks that is ported for mysql but the ms-sql version is pretty robust.